# Should history questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have had a number of questions that have far more to do with history than they really do with Christianity or doctrine.

Should these be on topic?

Some examples

- [What is the origin of the Catholic apocrypha?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/443/what-is-the-origin-of-the-apocrypha)
- [When was the OT canon as used by Protestants finalized?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/450/when-was-the-protestant-ot-canon-finalized)
- [When the Bible talks about wine does it mean alcoholic wine?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24/does-wine-really-mean-wine-in-the-bible)

What is our stance on the on topicness of these?

Answer (score 10):

Christianity is a historical religion. Prohibiting historical questions is going to mean prohibiting practically all but the most abstract discussion of Christianity.

So yes, in my view, history questions should be on-topic.

Comment: A `historical religion` could be read as offensive, couldn't it? As `out of date`.

Comment: I don't think it's offensive, nor do I think it means "out of date." I've heard Chrstianity called "historical" by countless authors and speakers, and their meaning is that it is based in history--as opposed to "made up on the spot" somewhere. To me, the historical aspect of Christianity is one of the strongest evidences that it is true, and therefore exactly the opposite of offensive.

Comment: The narrative sweep of the Bible is called "salvation history."